Science fiction short story where a boy eats cereal with coffee creamer
I've looked everywhere but I cannot find this story. I read it in 2017 on a school education site, or some other school assignment. From what I remember, the story goes:
A boy wakes up in his house and finds he is all alone. His doors and windows are all boarded up, but he cannot remember why. He is hungry, so he makes a bowl of cereal. Upon opening the fridge, he sees there's no milk, so he uses coffee creamer. According to him, it tastes bad but he eats it anyway. After some time, he starts to feel sick- and he hears a voice in his head, telling him to take the boards down. Something in his gut tells him not too, but the urge is too strong- he finds a hammer and peels the boards from the window down. As he does this, he remembers everything. His parents (and I think sister?) had been taken by robots and he had boarded up the windows before they could take him too. Outside the window are hundreds of flying robots, and the author tells us that he is the last human, but he gets captured by the robots.
The ending part where he takes down the boards is a bit fuzzy, but I'm confident this is how the story goes. Google does not help at all. I don't remember the author, but I was in 4th grade at the time I think. I think it was in the 2nd person as well, and there are no actual names in the story and I don't think there was any dialogue but there may have been dialogue from the robots at the end explaining they poisoned his coffee creamer. I even remember discussing this in class, asking how they could have poisoned it if his windows were boarded up.

Hi.  Welcome to SF&F!  I'm confused by one thing in your description; perhaps you can clarify.  You say he is all alone, but then when he takes the boards down the robots take his parents and sister?   Was he alone or not?

@Basya I think his family was taken before he put the boards up, but he doesn't remember it until he starts taking them down.

@CristobolPolychronopolis - thanks.

@Basya Thank you! But yes sorry for the confusion!! The boy's family had been taken by the robots before he put the boards up. he remembered why he put the boards up in the first place once he saw the robots out the window again

@Jester - thank you for the clarification.  Still have not found it though.....
